# How to schedule tasks in celery beat with canvas functionality

Tags: celery

Celery tasks have the limitation that they can not call subprocesses. Call backs and other canvas functionality is handled by how the tasks are called and related through the various canvas functions.
But when you schedule tasks through celery beat it appear that the only option is to call a single task without any of the canvas funcitons.
I need to schedule a task that has call backs. Is there anyway to do that in celery?
Its possible I could accomplish what I need in a single task but it would involve having significant memory overhead and take a long time to execute with many db hits. Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just generate the signature for whatever you need and pass it in the `options` dictionary. Here is a working `tasks.py` for a simple chain:

```python
from datetime import timedelta
from celery import Celery, signature

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost')
app.conf.update(
    beat_schedule={'add_divide': {'task': 'tasks.add',
                                  'args': (5, 7),
                                  'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),
                                   'options': {'queue': 'testq',
                                               'link': signature('tasks.divide',
                                                                 args=(4, ),
                                                                 queue='testq'
                                                  )
                                         }
                             }
                  }
)


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    z = x + y
    print('sum: {0}'.format(z))
    return z


@app.task
def divide(x, y):
    z = x / y
    print('divide: {0}'.format(z))
    return z
```

Running `celery worker -A tasks.celery -Q testq --beat -c1` will output something like:

```
[2017-04-07 00:00:00,000: WARNING/PoolWorker-2] sum: 12
[2017-04-07 00:00:00,050: WARNING/PoolWorker-2] divide: 3
```